# How to center an image in navigation Bar across all ViewController? Swift

Tags: swift, image, uinavigationcontroller

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 270, height: 30))
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

let image = UIImage(named: "image")
imageView.image = image
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true

self.navigationController?.navigationItem.titleView = imageView

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .black
```

Answer (score 0):

try with below updated code

```
let imageContainer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 270, height: 30))
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 270, height: 30))
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
let image = UIImage(named: "your_image")
imageView.image = image
imageContainer.addSubview(imageView)
navigationItem.titleView = imageContainer
```

Comment: what should replace logoContainer ?

Comment: have you use the TabBarController in your project?

Comment: @HamzaAlmass yes

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Navigation controller in the didFinishLaunching in app delegate file

```
window = UInavigationController(root: YourTabBarController)
```

Then add image to the navigation controller in the first view controller.
Will update the entire nav app